# Add number of days in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml as below:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <root>
        <row>
            <employee_id>1111</employee_id>
            <State>TX</State>
            <work_days>2</work_days>
        </row>
        <row>
            <employee_id>1111</employee_id>
            <State>FL</State>
            <work_days>9</work_days>
        </row>
        <row>
            <employee_id>2222</employee_id>
            <State>FL</State>
            <work_days>7</work_days>
        </row>
        <row>
            <employee_id>2222</employee_id>
            <State>NC</State>
            <work_days>1</work_days>
        </row>
```

I need to group the state and work_days data for each employee and then sum up the Work_days for each group separately.(Please see the **Sum** tag below)

```
Expected output:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <row>
            <employee_id>1111</employee_id>
            <Data>
                <State>TX</State>
                <Work_days>2</Work_days>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <State>FL</State>
                <Work_days>9</Work_days>
            </Data>
           <Sum>11</Sum>         <----------
        </row>
        <row>
            <employee_id>2222</employee_id>
            <Data>
                <State>FL</State>
                <Work_days>7</Work_days>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <State>NC</State>
                <Work_days>1</Work_days>
            </Data>
           <Sum>8</Sum>         <----------
        </row>
```

I am able to group them using below xslt but not able to sum up the wark_days:

```
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="employee_id">
                <row>
                    <employee_id><xsl:value-of select="employee_id" /></employee_id>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        
                        <Data> 
                            <State><xsl:value-of select="State" /></State>
                            <Work_days><xsl:value-of select="work_days" /></Work_days>
                        </Data> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(work_days)"/></sum>         <----------
                </row>    
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I am getting now is:

```
   <row>
      <employee_id>1111</employee_id>
      <Data>
         <State>TX</State>
         <Work_days>2</Work_days>
      </Data>
      <Data>
         <State>FL</State>
         <Work_days>9</Work_days>
      </Data>
      <sum>2</sum>         <----------
   </row>
   <row>
      <employee_id>2222</employee_id>
      <Data>
         <State>FL</State>
         <Work_days>7</Work_days>
      </Data>
      <Data>
         <State>NC</State>
         <Work_days>1</Work_days>
      </Data>
      <sum>7</sum>         <----------
   </row>
```

Please help to get the sum properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/work_days)"/>`